# Possible reasons my *really* old pc cant handle my new vDSL connection?

Tags: windows-7, networking

For the time being, I have to stick with my really old machine. In it, there is an [ASUS P5N32-E SLI](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5N32E_SLI/) mainboard. From the specs I'd guess it should be able to handle 120.000 DSL.

This is what happens:

When browsing or surfing and downloading stuff, the internet connection keeps breaking. From what I've seen, I believe it is beyond 3 or 4 mbps. Windows (7, 64 bit) alerts me that the internet connection has a problem (duh).

I can fix this by going into the system settings, disable/ deactivate the lan adapter and enabling it again, it takes about a minute. But then, the game starts all over again.

When I use a download client where I can set a **maximum download speed**, the connection stays fine. As I said, it is around 3 to 4 mbps.

The reason I believe its a pc related problem is that while the connection is gone other devices in the wifi do have a proper connection.

I've updated all drivers. The networking driver seems to be an NVIDIA nforce 680i dontaskme thing. Still, all drivers up-to-date.

> For clarification:
>
> I am using a regular DSL router ([unitymedia/ connect box](https://www.unitymedia.de/content/dam/unitymedia-de/assets-de/pdf/Connect-Box-Interaktives-Benutzerhandbuch.pdf) (German,
>   sorry)) and directly plug the networking cable from the modem into the
>   pc. PPPoE is enabled.
>
> The WiFi is not related to the LAN or the pc. I was just mentioning that while
>   my pc has no internet connection, other devices do (WiFi is not
>   important I guess).
>
> The problem is not Windows complaining. The problem is no internet :)

Any clues?

[Network cable in use](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B000NWPY3S/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: Your description is not accurate enough. How is your PC's LAN adapter related to the mentioned WiFi clients? Is your PC handling the DSL connection via PPPoE and a DSL modem, or is your PC simply connected to your TCP/IP LAN and a DSL Modem router is handling the connection? Finally, do you even have any problems beyond WIndows complaining about the connection, or is the complaint your only problem while everything is running fine? I suggest you address these points with more clarity.

Comment: @ClassStacker thanks for your hints, I've updated my question. I hope there is nothing unclear left

Comment: I still don't understand the WiFi part. Is your PC providing the WiFi through the PPPoE and DSL modem? If not, how is the WiFI provided; is it related to the topic at all?

Comment: @ClassStacker I was just saying: the modem has 4 lan ports and provides wifi. The computer is connected via lan, while other devices are connected via wifi. When the pc has no internet connection, my other devices (that are connected via wifi) still have - so I guess its not a modem/router but a pc problem. the pc does not have anything to do with wifi

Comment: Then that's not a modem, it's a DSL modem router, and your PC shouldn't use PPPoE but rather connect to the TCP/IP LAN. In other words, the DSL modem router manages the internet connection, not your PC. The only problem can be on TCP/IP layer. What speed is negotiated for your PC's LAN port, and which category does the LAN cable have?

Comment: Your lan adaptor might be dying.

Comment: @ClassStacker thanks for heads up. Im not familiar with what PPPoE means or does, but I didnt configure it anyhow on the pc itself. The router has it enabled (I believe) but I didnt activate in particular on the pc. It worked with another router before, so I guess its not a PPPoE thing but I will check it. The mainboard spec says "Gigabit LAN". The cable is cat 5.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek so would buying a pci network card be a good idea?

Comment: I'd try the most obvious and replace the LAN cable. A CAT 5 LAN cable is not appropriate if your DSL modem router and your PC negotiate gigabit speed. The other router (with which everything worked) may have negotiated a slower spped on the LAN port, for which the CAT 5 may have been suitable.

Comment: Maybe you did already check some TCP/IP configuration, like IPv6 disabled or flow control for the networkcard, if avaiable ?

Comment: I've had terrible luck with some pci gigabit ethernet cards. I'd be a *bit* picky, go over to hardware recommendations and see if anyone can recommend a good, cheap *intel* based card. I was looking at getting one as a spare and for some networking experiments. Most common cards are realtek and *suck*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thanks, im going a tp link card. its not a good one either but its only a temporary solution till my new build is ready :)

Comment: Again, the first thing is to eliminate the first problem, which is your CAT 5 LAN cable. But of course you can go and spend money for an ethernet card. Millions of PCs run with non-Intel driven gigabit LAN ports. Not to mention your router.

Comment: @ClassStacker I bought a card and a cable :)

Comment: hey guys, it actually was the gigabit adapter. bought a pci gigabit card and its working fine. anyways, ive also bought a cat7 cable :) @JourneymanGeek would you mind post an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Tonny's answer covers that. Pick it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is pretty old, but should be able to handle Internet speeds at least 10x that high without issues. I downloaded a 4GB ISO file yesterday on a P4 system (even older hardware) and got a steady 250 Mb/s.

Based upon your information and the comments I would recommend the following:

1. Swap the LAN cable for a CAT5-E or (better) CAT6 cable. Regular CAT5, especially cables that are several years old (cables can degrade with time), can have issues with Gigabit speeds. This may result in exactly the problems you are seeing.
2. It is possible the Nvidia on-board ethernet adapter has issues anyway with Gigabit (which may not have shown in combination with the previous router). And the drivers (any version) for this particular adapter are known to be quite flaky (I had lot's of issues with a number of different motherboards based around the same chipset). The only way around that is getting a new PCI ethernet card. Just about any cheap card (€15 or so) will do.